# How do I transfer subscription of Google Drive to an existing google account?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-workspace, google-drive-shared-drive

I recently migrated a client's emails to Gsuite and set up a workspace account for them. This included the following emails (not actually their emails)

- John@company.com
- Jane@company.com
- Info@company.com - with aliases set up for work@company.net & admin@company.net (these were old emails
  which were migrated over into archive folders and set up as alias under the primary account - not actual email accounts) There was also an old email called info@company.net which was migrated into an archive folder (no alias was set up for this).

Following the migration, I found out that: They also have a Google account set up under info@company.net (the email which is now archived under Info@company.com and discontinued - i.e. I did not set up a new user or alias after I migrated the mails). This account holds their Drive folders and has a 1tb storage subscription (among other things such as YouTube, Ads, Analytics) and is essential to their business and all users need access to this.

The problem now is that when they try to sign into the Drive under info@company.net, they are told:

[image]

When they try to add the info@company.net email it changes over to info%company.net@gtempaccount.com and is causing the team a lot of headaches every time they login (as far as I can see this is not a conflicting account - it's not set up as a user or alias under the new workspace).

Can anyone think of a solution to this so that they still have easy access to their 1tb Google Drive subscription and other apps while also being signed in to their newly set up Google workspace accounts for emails? Is there any way to transfer this subscription to the newly set up Google account Info@company.com?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The company.net domain is separate from the company.com domain. When the new domain used an alias with the same name as the old domain the email accounts on the old domain with the same username are treated as conflicting accounts, such the renaming option.

Since these are separate domains, you have to migrate the data on the old .net domain to the .com domain. For example, in Google Drive, you have different options of migrating:

> Google Drive   Download—Your users can download Drive files to their
> computer and move them to Drive in their new Google Workspace account.
> For details, go to [downloading a file](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2423534/).
>
> Export and import—Use the [Drive REST API](https://developers.google.com/drive/).
>
> Share—You can individually share files with people in your new
> account.

Then you can proceed with [deleting the company.net account](https://support.google.com/a/answer/9468554), removing the conflict.

References:

[Transfer Data between Google Workspace Accounts](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1041297?hl=en/)

[Delete your organization's Google Workspace Account](https://support.google.com/a/answer/9468554)

[Transfer ownership of a Google Ads, Google Analytics, or Google Merchant Center account](https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/44500?hl=en)

Comment: I think the above works for the Drive folders (thanks) but what about other apps used with the old domain/account such as Ads, Analytics or YouTube? Would deleting the old account not delete these also? Is there a way to transfer ownership of these accounts to the new account?

Comment: The listed reference [Transfer Data between Google Workspace Accounts](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1041297?hl=en/) should have different instructions for different products like Analytics or YouTube.

Adsense has a different page [here](https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/44500?hl=en).